# Locust IO failures 'BadStatusCode' meaning

Tags: python, httprequest, load-testing, locust

I'm using locust to load test APIs, but every time I'm testing API which need parameter other than authorization to be inputted like this:

[image: API which need data inputted]

It always fail at 100% which says 'BadStatusCode('endpoint',)', already google what does it mean and search locust error documentation but I still haven't found any clue. Every other API (mainly API with method other than get) I test with locust which only need parameter authorization like this:

[image: API with only authorization parameter]

run perfectly fine. I already google various locust code on how to input parameters to endpoint and I think my code already correct.

Here's my code (with 100% failures):

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from locust import TaskSet, task, between, HttpLocust
from locust.contrib.fasthttp import FastHttpLocust
import resource
from dotenv import dotenv_values

load_dotenv()
resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_NOFILE, (65536, 999999))

host_p = os.getenv("HOST_P")
header = {
    'authorization': 'Bearer ' + os.getenv('TOKEN')
}

values = {
    "amount": 100
}
    
def payment(self):
    self.client.post("/pay", headers=header, json=values)

class ProcessPost(TaskSet):
    tasks={payment:2}

class ApiPost(FastHttpLocust):
    host = host_payment
    task_set = ProcessPost
    wait_time = between(5.0, 9.0)
```

and here's my other code (run perfectly fine):

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from locust import TaskSet, task, between, HttpLocust
from locust.contrib.fasthttp import FastHttpLocust
import resource
import datetime as d
from dotenv import dotenv_values
import json

load_dotenv()
resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_NOFILE, (65536, 999999))

host_p = os.getenv("HOST_P")
header = {
    'authorization': 'Bearer ' + os.getenv('TOKEN')
}

def payment(self):
    self.client.get("/pay", headers=header)

class ProcessPost(TaskSet):
    tasks={payment:2}

class ApiPost(FastHttpLocust):
    host = host_payment
    task_set = ProcessPost
    wait_time = between(5.0, 9.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is probably you are sending data as body and not adding content type header , if you use json instead it adds content-type header itself, but you need to add it yourself if you use data to pass values.

```
    headers['Content-Type'] = "application/json"
```

Comment: Hello! thanks for your answer and really appreciate that, however it seems does not work with me. I already change data to json as after futher research just realized data is for request with Form Data (you can see it in https://www.swtestacademy.com/post-request-and-jsonpath-usage-with-locust/), meanwhile mine is JSON. So i changed it to json. I already edit my question in which I put my code which run perfectly

Comment: other than that all i can say is if server side is case sensitive it might be because of 'authorization' / 'Authorization' , you can print the response if the server returns an error message in body for further debugging

Comment: Hi, thanks again for the answer, will do like you suggested and keep you updated about the results!